# Cannot get pending transactions from geth (Ropsten revival testnet)

Tags: go-ethereum

I'm using Ropsten (revival) testnet with geth.
I can see that all blocks are the same as
https://ropsten.etherscan.io/
But I cannot see the pending transactions.

From https://ropsten.etherscan.io/txsPending
there are about 16 pending transactions but when I do

```
> eth.pendingTransactions
```

with geth, I get and empty list: []

How can I get the list of pending transactions ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`eth.pendingTransactions` only lists the transactions that you have issued. If you want to look at pending transactions for the whole network, check out [`txpool`](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/rpc/ns-txpool)

Specifically, `txpool.inspect` gives you a nice shorthand view. From there you can use `eth.getTransaction(txid)` for any individual transaction that you want to know more about.

Comment: Any hint how to filter/get transactions only for specific pair (pool) i.e. `mycoin/bnb` ?